# JSON POST with an array parameter with content-type x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I'm trying to send a JSON request to a third party API. It seems like the issue is related to sending an array of data (hotels and party).

I'm using RestSharp for the request which looks like this (it's just a test for now, will fix it once the request works).

```
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    var client = new RestClient(_Url);
    request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "username=test&password=test&hotels=%5B%7B%22partner_id%22%3A%20%2214%22%7D%5D&start_date=2017-08-01&end_date=2017-08-05&party=%5B%7B%22adults%22%3A%202%7D%5D&lang=en_US&currency=EUR&user_country=GR&device_type=d", ParameterType.RequestBody);

    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

When I send the request, I receive the response of "max() [function.max]: Array must contain at least one element".

According to the suppliers limited documentation, the format of the request is as follows;

```
 username=test
 &password=test
 &hotels=[{"partner_id":"14"},{"partner_id":"16"}]
 &start_date=2013-07-01
 &end_date=2013-07-03
 &party=[{“adults": 2}]
 &lang=en_US
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try adding each parameter separately? request.AddParameter("name", "value")

Comment: Just tried that and receive error response of request is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Suppliers documentation was incorrect!